# Facing issue with Dynamic Unpivot in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, unpivot

[Desired Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Hzo.png)

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgEvS.png)

I am using the script below to achieve this:

```
DECLARE myunpivot STRING;
SET myunpivot = (
  SELECT CONCAT('(', STRING_AGG( column_name, ','), ')'),
From(
SELECT column_name FROM `ProjectA.ProjectA1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
where table_name ="my_table" 
));


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""

SELECT * FROM `ProjectA.ProjectA1.table_name`
unpivot
(
  columns 
  FOR value in %s
)
""", myunpivot);
```

I am getting this error- "Unexpected Keyword DECLARE" although I ensured that DECLARE statement is the first line in my code.

On removing the DECLARE statement, I am getting this error- "Executing OTHER_STATEMENT statements is not implemented"

I am not able to figure out what the issue is over here. Please Help!

Comment: I used your query but I did not ran into errors mentioned above. I did not change anything except the tables (changed into my sample tables) Problem I can think of is you have some texts that got selected/highlighted. Can you try selecting your whole block of query and press Ctrl + E ?

Comment: Hi Nestor. Thanks for responding. I think this has something to do with Google Bigquery. I tried an alternative approach as well but it gives me this error-  "Executing OTHER_STATEMENT statements is not implemented". There is hardly any info on web regarding this error. I am using the exact same code others have used for dynamic unpivot on bigquery but I seem to be the only one facing this issue.